# writeUTF adds null to output

Tags: java

```
for(int i=0;i<charset.size(); i++ )
       {
       String plaintext1= charset.get(i); 
       fos= new FileOutputStream("/root/something.txt", true);
       dos= new DataOutputStream(fos);
       String hashtext=CreateHash.returnString(charset.get(i));
        dos.writeUTF('\n'+plaintext1+" ="+hashtext);
       fos.close();
       dos.close();
       }
```

When I execute this code (there's more), I get < nul >$  after each line and at the start of the page. I'm opening the text file with nedit.

Comment: what is your expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is *precisely* what [writeUTF](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#writeUTF%28java.lang.String%29) is documented to do. If you don't want this behavior, don't ask for it.

> First, *two bytes are written to the output stream as if by the `writeShort` method giving the number of bytes to follow*. This value is the number of bytes actually written out, not the length of the string. Following the length, each character of the string is output, in sequence, using the modified UTF-8 encoding for the character.

Comment: I have not heard about this behaviour

Answer (score 0):

DataOutputStream is a bad choice for writing text. It is designed to write different Java data types and read them with a Java program. Take java.io.BufferedWriter (Java 7 style example)

```
    try (BufferedWriter wrt = Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get("file"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
        wrt.write("text");
    }
```